# Live Graph in HighCharts

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I wanted to draw a live graph from highcharts library using data from my backend server via AJAX calls.

I've followed this [link](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update) of Highcharts and was not able to grab the logic(being a beginner). Please read the comments.

```
$(function () {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        Highcharts.setOptions({
            global: {
                useUTC: false
            }
        });

        var chart;
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'spline',
                animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
                marginRight: 10,
                events: {
                    load: function() {


                        var series = this.series[0];
           // WHY X AND Y ARE SPECIFIED OVER HERE

                        setInterval(function() {
                            var x = (new Date()).getTime(), 
                                y = Math.random();
                            series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                        }, 1000);
                    }
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Live random data'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                tickPixelInterval: 150
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Value'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                        return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                        Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) +'<br/>'+
                        Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            exporting: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Random data',
                data: (function() {
        //AND ALSO OVER HERE
                    var data = [],
                        time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                        i;

                    for (i = -19; i <= 0; i++) {
                        data.push({
                            x: time + i * 1000,
                            y: Math.random()
                        });
                    }
                    return data;
                })()
            }]
        });
    });

});
```

AND I need to make an AJAX call. Where should I make it.

Here is my **AJAX** function

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/dashboard/",
      data : { 'live_energy_data' : 'live_energy_data' },
      success : function(result){

      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `setInterval` function you need to call ajax and get data (i.e as JSON) then use setData / addSeries / addPoint / pointUpdate

```
    setInterval(function() {

               $.ajax(url,function(data){
                    var x = data.x, 
                                y = data.y;
                            series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
               });

    }, 1000);
```

All functions are documented here http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts

Comment: Then what is data in series used for?